# "TemplateBinding' used after '{' must be a Markup Extension" Error on UWP GridView

Tags: xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I have a GridView on my MainPage.xaml. I wanted the change outermost border brush color in GeneratedItemContainerStyle:

[image: Screenshot]

So, I created a new custom style by clicking "Edit a Copy" from GridView/Additional Templates/GeneratedItemContainerStyle.

Then, this XAML style appeared in my App.xaml.

```xml
<Style x:Key="GridViewItemStyle1" TargetType="GridViewItem">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource GridViewItemBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource GridViewItemForeground}"/>
    <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
    <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,4,4"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource GridViewItemMinWidth}"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource GridViewItemMinHeight}"/>
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-2"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualPrimaryBrush" Value="{ThemeResource GridViewItemFocusVisualPrimaryBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualPrimaryThickness" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualSecondaryBrush" Value="{ThemeResource GridViewItemFocusVisualSecondaryBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualSecondaryThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
                <ListViewItemPresenter CheckBrush="{ThemeResource GridViewItemCheckBrush}" ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" CheckMode="{ThemeResource GridViewItemCheckMode}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource GridViewItemCheckBoxBrush}" DragForeground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemDragForeground}" DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" DragBackground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemDragBackground}" DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}" FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualPrimaryBrush}" FocusVisualSecondaryThickness="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualSecondaryThickness}" FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource GridViewItemFocusBorderBrush}" FocusVisualMargin="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualMargin}" FocusVisualPrimaryThickness="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualPrimaryThickness}" FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource GridViewItemFocusSecondaryBorderBrush}" FocusVisualSecondaryBrush="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualSecondaryBrush}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True" PointerOverForeground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemForegroundPointerOver}" PressedBackground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemBackgroundPressed}" PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemPlaceholderBackground}" PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemBackgroundPointerOver}" ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource GridViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" SelectedPressedBackground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemBackgroundSelectedPressed}" SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="{ThemeResource GridViewItemSelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled}" SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemForegroundSelected}" SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver}" SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemBackgroundSelected}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

After that, I tried to deploy my app, this error appeared:

> Type 'TemplateBinding' used after '{' must be a Markup Extension. Error code 0x09c4.** in ListViewItemPresenter section of XAML code.

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `FocusVisual*` properties exist only in the Anniversary update. You seed to set the min SDK version in your project properties to "Windows 10 Anniversary Edition" (typically build 14393).

Are you talking about the 2px border that each GridViewItem has? This isn't a focus border; you'll have to override these resources:

```xml
<GridView>
    <GridView.Resources>
        <!--
            These will apply to this GridView only. Put in higher scope
            (page or app) depending on what you want it to affect.
        -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GridViewItemBackgroundSelected" Color="Red"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GridViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver" Color="Blue"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GridViewItemBackgroundSelectedPressed" Color="LimeGreen"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GridViewItemBackgroundPointerOver" Color="Magenta"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GridViewItemBackgroundPressed" Color="Violet"/>
    </GridView.Resources>
</GridView>
```

Comment: Thanks. No, I'm not talking about the 2px border that each GridViewItem has. I mean focus border.